# Magit fail git pre-commit hook with No such file or directory

Tags: magit, python

I have a git pre-commit hook to run the unittest locally on my GNU/Linux manchine. The content of my `pre-commit` file is

```
#!/bin/bash

source activate project && python manage.py test && pylint project
```

And my `.git/config` has

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    hooksPath = /path/to/project/hooks
```

`git commit` runs without problem from the command line.

```
$ git --version
git version 2.14.1
$ git commit -am "Some message"
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
............................................................................................
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 92 tests in 12.873s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...

--------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 10.00/10 (previous run: 10.00/10, +0.00)

[395 c7d2b5c] Some message
 1 file changed, 7 insertions(+), 6 deletions(-)
```

but Magit fails with

```
  1 git … commit --
/path/to/project/hooks/pre-commit: line 3: activate: No such file or directory
```

I'm using [conda](https://conda.io/) as a virtual environment manager and `source activate project` [is their recommendation](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#activating-an-environment).

Answer (score 1):

Following [this advice](https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/1436#issuecomment-49814617) by [Jonas Bernoulli](https://github.com/tarsius) solved my problem: install https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell and follow the instructions on what to put in `~/.emacs` (or, preferably, `~/.emacs.d/init.el`).

Comment: Could you please edit your question to confirm that you're on Mac OS?

Comment: @Dan I'm using GNU/Linux. I edit it.

Comment: You can accept your own answer. (Though generally it is a good idea to delay doing so for a little while, not to discourage other answers.)